# Oracle schema wise replication selection

Tags: replication, oracle-12c

We have 2 Oracle DB schema (ABC, XYZ) in two geographies (site 1 and site 2) where both schemas are running on separate cluster. Schema ABC has golden gate replication between site 1 and 2 and is an Active-Active database. Database XYZ has data guard replication between site 1 and site 2 and is an Active-Passive database. Now we want to scrap the host servers of schema ABC and unfortunately cannot provision new ones. Only option is to import the schema to the same cluster as of XYZ. Can we have Active-Active replication for ABC using GG and Active-Passive replication for XYZ using Data Guard in the same Database hosts across sites ?